# Image/button/circle on top of camera preview using Phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using **Phonegap**. Is there any method to display image or button or circle on top of camera preview. I am also using Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 0):

I think not without programming native, ie objective-c for iphone. What device do you target?

On iphone you can add a `cameraOverlayView` to the `UIImagePickerController`.